# How to give a blank line to an InputStream using IOUtils.toInputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing, io

I have code which consumes an `InputStream` through a `Scanner` which looks like

```
String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
if (input.isEmpty()) {
    return defaultAnswer;
} else if (input.startsWith("y")) {
    return true;
} else if (input.startsWith("n")) {
    return false;
}
```

where the scanner is initialized by a given `InputStream` coming from `IOUtils.toInputStream("someString")`.

How would I be able to test the `if (input.isEmpty())` path?

**EDIT:**

I swapped two lines in my code, and empty string (`""`) results in a `NoSuchElementException`, and a newline or carriage return results in an empty string being returned.

Answer (score 2):

Either using `IOUtils.toInputStream("")` or `new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0])` may work.

The latter would certainly provide an empty stream, but it may make your code fail because there isn't an empty line to read - there's no line terminator. For example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }    
}
```

That fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

You can use `Scanner.hasNextLine()` to check whether a call to `nextLine()` is appropriate or not. You *may* want to do that in your code. It really depends on whether you're trying to model "input ended without a line" or "the user entered an empty line". Those are significantly different situations, and you should *consider* both of them.

If you want to provide a stream which contains a line break (i.e. "the user entered an empty line") then you might want to use `IOUtils.toInputStream("\n")` instead. I'm nervous about the fact that that's not specifying a `Charset` though - you should carefully consider what encoding you expect your input to be in.

Comment: `IOUtils` is a class from the Apache io-commons package that turns a string into an `InputStream` with the contents of the string

Comment: @EdJoJob: Okay, I've edited slightly; in particular, see the bottom paragraph.

Comment: There is the option for the charset it in the newer api, where the older, string only method is depreciated.